# crear directivas de blade

Tags: laravel, blade, directivas

Estoy intentando crear una directiva de Blade para Laravel, para definir campos de contraseña. La idea es que estos campos sean de un **input-group**, y se declaren con una sola línea. Lo que he hecho en el método `boot()` del `AppServiceProvider` es lo siguiente:

```
Blade::directive('password', function ($def) {
    $def = explode(",", $def);
    foreach ($def as $k=>$v) $def[$k] = str_replace('"', '', trim($v));
    $field = "<div class='input-group'>";
    $field .= "<input type='password' id='".$def[0]."' name='".$def[1]."' class=\"form-control @error('".$def[1]."') is-invalid @enderror ".$def[2]."\">";
    $field .= "<div class='input-group-append'>";
    $field .= "<i class='pw-icon far fa-eye'></i>";
    $field .= "</div>";
    $field .= "</div>";
    return $field;
});
```

En la vista intento invocar esta directiva para generar el campo, con un icono asociado, como se ve en la definición de la directiva. En el código HTML generado en el navegador el campo aparece definido así:

```
<div class='input-group'><input type='password' id='clave' name='clave' class="form-control @error('clave') is-invalid @enderror "><div class='input-group-append'><i class='pw-icon far fa-eye'></i></div></div>
```

Lo que tengo en el archivo `vista.blade.php` para usar la directiva es lo siguiente:

```
@password("clave", "clave", "")
```

Los tres parámetros pretenden ser el atributo `id` del campo que pretendo generar con la directiva, su atributo `name`, y el tercero lo reservo para añadir otra posible clase.

Un desastre, por varias razones. En primer lugar, el campo incluye la directiva `@error`, para determinar si hay que aplicarle o no la clase `is-invalid`. Pero Blade ya no procesa esto. Lo toma como texto, y la clase la aplica siempre, haya o no error.
Otro problema con este código es que no "coge" el icono de font-awesome, y no construye correctamente el input-group.
¿Cual sería la forma correcta de definir esta directiva? Como puedo documentarme mejor sobre la creación de directivas blade más o menos sofisticadas?

Comment: Creo que lo que realmente necesitas es un `component`, una directiva no debería usarse así.

Comment: Deberías especificar en qué versión de laravel estás trabajando.

Comment: Estoy usando la 5.8, pero por lo que he visto esta funcionalidad la pusieron en la 5.5 y creo que no ha cambiado hasta la actual 8.

Comment: Hola, yo también estoy con una directiva que no acaba de funcionar. Creo que para el uso concreto que necesitas tienes una en este repo: https://github.com/oricis/laravel-blade-directives#fa-fas-far-fal-fab-fad-mdi-glyph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La teoría básica:

Puedes **crear directivas Blade** directamente en el *AppServiceProvicer*, ejemplo:

Añades "Blade" en la cabecera del fichero:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
```

Dentro del método `boot()` "creas" tu directiva:

```
Blade::directive('xxx', function (
    $something
) {
    return $something;
});
```

En este caso solo devuelvo directamente el parámetro: lo que le pases en el template Blade lo imprimirá "directamente". Entonces, usas la nueva directiva:

```
@xxx(Lorem ipsum)
@xxx('Lorem ipsum')
```

La página mostrará:

```
Lorem ipsum 'Lorem ipsum'
```

Algo importante a tener en cuenta, **todo lo que recibe una directiva como parámetro es un string**... (llega al *closure* de la directiva como tal) entonces si usas una variable para pasar un valor:

```
@xxx($someContent)
```

La página mostrará:

```
$someContent
```

*Se muestra el nombre de la variable y no su contenido, porque la directiva recibio un string.*

#### Notas:

- Probado en *Laravel 7*.
- Al introducir cambios en la directiva *no siempre* se reflejan automáticamente en la vista. Puedes cambiar algo en el *template* o usar `php artisan view:clear` para ver si todo funciona.
- Si vas a añadir *directivas Blade* a un proyecto deberías **crear un ServiceProvider** a este fin.

#### Extra:

- Artículo sobre directivas Blade: https://www.laraveltip.com/crear-directivas-personalizadas-con-blade-en-laravel/
- Repositorio con varias directivas: https://github.com/oricis/laravel-blade-directives